# Reading and resizing svs slide results in a damaged image

Tags: python-imaging-library, openslide

I'm using OpenSlide and PIL to open slides and resize them. For some of the slides, the resulting images are partly black. To reproduce the error, use [this](https://portal.gdc.cancer.gov/files/5b54f176-3727-4a02-aa7a-921eebe5aeea) slide and this script:

```
def slide_to_scaled_pil_image(slide, SCALE_FACTOR=32):
  """
  Convert a WSI training slide to a scaled-down PIL image.
  Args:
    slide: An OpenSlide object.
  Returns:
    Tuple consisting of scaled-down PIL image, original width, original height, new width, and new height.
  """

  large_w, large_h = slide.dimensions
  new_w = math.floor(large_w / SCALE_FACTOR)
  new_h = math.floor(large_h / SCALE_FACTOR)
  level = slide.get_best_level_for_downsample(SCALE_FACTOR)
  whole_slide_image = slide.read_region((0, 0), level, slide.level_dimensions[level])
  whole_slide_image = whole_slide_image.convert("RGB")
  img = whole_slide_image.resize((new_w, new_h), PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
  return img, large_w, large_h, new_w, new_h

img = openslide.OpenSlide(PATH_TO_SLIDE)
ds_img, large_w, large_h, new_w, new_h = slide_to_scaled_pil_image(img, SCALE_FACTOR=SCALE_FACTOR)
```

So if I use different `SCALE_FACTOR` I end up with a different result (`ds_img`). `SCALE_FACTOR=32`
produces this:
[image: damaged slide]

while `SCALE_FACTOR=64` produces this:
[image: normal slide]

What is the problem here? Is there a way to overcome this issue if I need to use `SCALE_FACTOR=32`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using exactly the same tiling pipeline you're using (and on the same TCGA data) and found the same weird results.

What fixed it to me was to upgrade (download/build) the latest version of the `pixman` library to 0.40.0. You will need to upgrade the corresponding Python modules as well, especially `pillow` and `pixman`.

There are tons of discussion here -  https://github.com/openslide/openslide/issues/291 - and throughout GitHub (just follow the threads).